# TWRP 0MB Internal storage issue

Tags: twrp

I have a Lenovo tab 4-10 TBX304L
I flashed it with TWRP and It shows 0 MB for Internal storage.
I Tried changing file system to ext 2 and ext4.wiped data and system.
Reinstalled android stock rom via QFIL tool.
Any help?

Comment: fastboot format:ext4 userdata

Comment: Tried it......Even formatted data.....

Comment: after formatting, boot straight into TWRP (*fastboot boot <file>*) otherwise partition becomes encrypted again

Comment: Well Ill tell U Brother!!!..After flashing twrp....ill let u know if it works...Thankss